# How to select records from a Table that has a certain number of rows in a related table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not quite sure how to ask this, but I have 2 tables that are related in a 1 to many relationship, I need to select all records in the "1" table that have less than three records in the "many' table.

```
select b.foreignkey,count(b.foreignkey) as bidcount
from b 
where b.foreignkey in (select a.id from a) and bidcount< 3 
group by b.foreignkey
```

this doesn't work at all I know but I am at a loss how to do this.

I need to in the end select all the records from the "a" table based on this criteria. Sorry if that is confusing!

Comment: do you want all columns from the "a" table or just the foreign key?

Comment: i was going to get certain columns. once i had the foreignkeys from the query i mentioned, i then got results based on if those ids were in table "a"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using your code, not tested:

```
SELECT
   b.foreignkey,
   count(b.foreignkey) as bidcount 
FROM 
   b
WHERE 
   b.foreignkey IN (SELECT a.id FROM a) 
GROUP BY 
   b.foreignkey 
HAVING 
   count(b.foreignkey) < 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.id,COUNT(t2.parentId)
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2
ON t1.id = t2.parentId
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING COUNT(t2.parentId) < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention **which version** of SQL Server you're using - if you're on SQL Server 2005 or newer, you could use this CTE (Common Table Expression):

```
;WITH ChildRows AS
(
   SELECT A.Id, COUNT(b.Id) AS 'BCount'
   FROM
      dbo.TableA A
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.TableB B ON B.TableAId = A.Id
)     
SELECT A.*, R.BCount
FROM dbo.TableA A
INNER JOIN ChildRows R ON A.Id = R.Id
```

The inner `SELECT` lists the `Id` columns from `TableA` and the count of the child rows associated with those (using the `INNER JOIN` to `TableB`) - and the outer `SELECT` just builds on top of that result set and shows all fields from table A (and the count from the B table)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return all fields of your (1) table in one query, I suggest you consider using CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table_1 t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM Table_Many t2 WHERE t2.fk = t1.pk) a
where a.cnt < 3
```

in some particular cases, based on your indices and db structure, this query may run 4 times faster than the `GROUP BY` method

Answer (score 0):

you have posted this question in sql server, I have a answer in oracle database system (don't know whether it will run in sql server as well or not)

this is as follow-

```
select [desired column list] from 
    (select b.*, count(*) over (partition by b.foreignkey) c_1
      from b
     where b.foreignkey in (select a.id from a) )

where c_1 < 3 ;
```

i hope it should work on sql server as well...
if not please let me update ..